# Get the comment of a specific User- Facebook API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-comments

I want to get the list of comments made by given user through Facebook Graph API.

I haven't found any direct way to get lists of comments. So, I tried to find them through my feed, but it's returning all feed posts. Can we filter other posts where I have not commented?

I tried various queries as below, but could not get exactly what I need.

```
/me/feed?fields=comments?fields=from?name="my_name",message

/me/feed?fields=comments.fields(from.name("my_name"),message)
```

I need either (1) list of all comments by me or else (2) lists of posts which I have commented on, filtering out all other posts.
How can we do this?

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to filter via the Graph API. Basically what you want to achieve is IMHO not really possible.

What you could theoretically do is use the `comment` FQL table, but the field you'd need (`fromid`) is not indexable: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/comment/ So this could be tough.